# On a press of the button : Hide keyboard in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this [simple screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn1Km.jpg)

when I press in button the keyboard still apear How can I do this :  " On a press of the button : Hide keyboard" ?

> here is my code for button

```
        manage = () => {
           const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        if (this.state.text.length === 10) {

          navigate('service',{text: this.state.text});
        } else {
        Alert.alert('الرجاء ادخال الرقم  الوطني المكون من 10 أرقام')
        }
        }
        <Button   title='التالي'
           backgroundColor="#C1272D"
   onPress={this.manage}>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'; 

Keyboard.dismiss()//Call where ever you needed
```

Docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard)

Comment: Works, very easy to use!